# OAuth2 access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, google-oauth

I'm working on a site that uses OAuth 2, and I'm having some issues with Google's sign-in process.

Everything works perfectly until I go to fetch the access token. WHen I do this with facebook, it is returned url-encoded, just like the spec:

```
access_token={access-token}&expires={seconds-til-expiration}
```

When I do the same thing with Google, I get the same data, but in json, also per the speec I could find:

```
{
  "access_token":"1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "expires_in":3920,
  "token_type":"Bearer"
}
```

Is this to be expected, and is there anything I can do to make either one of them conform with the other? Or do I just have to suck it up and write my code to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is not the only inconsistency you will find with different OAuth providers. `scopes` are (naturally) different, `user profile` will be also different (e.g. you will get **last_name** in one, and **family_name** in another one, both meaning the same). In [our system](http://developers.auth0.com), we chose to *normalize* all providers into a common representation. We also hide the differences between different providers. But in our case, we deal with a rather large number of providers, and we want to provide a single interface to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Google returns the results according to the spec:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.1

Requests are sent in URL encoded format. Responses at the token endpoint are always JSON.